# Blinking cursor on boot after upgrade

Tags: boot

I have a blank screen with only a blinking cursor after upgrade via deselect responds to nothing! Have tried options F2, still zip on reboot
. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try Dropping to the root shell. (Hold shift on startup) Then select the drop to root shell option. Make sure that you did a full upgrade and it wasn't interrupted halfway through or something and if it was then try reupdating from the terminal.